# How to run the same task in parallel on multiple hosts with different parameters using fabric?

Tags: python, fabric

demo.py

```
from fabric.api import env, run,execute

env.hosts = ['10.1.1.100','10.1.1.200']
env.remotePath = {'10.1.1.100':'/home','10.1.1.200':'/var'}
env.parallel=True

def mytask(remotePath):
    run('ls %s' % remotePath)

def test():
    execute(mytask,env.remotePath[env.host])
```

fab -f demo.py test

I want to execute command `ls /home` at 10.1.1.100,and `ls /var` at 10.1.1.200 in parallel using @parallel decorator,is there any way to make it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Use `host_string` to get the current host, then the command/argument you want to use.

```
@parallel
def mytask():
  host_ip = env.host_string
  remote_path = env.remotePath[host_ip]
  run('ls %s' % remote_path)
```

According to Fabric's API doc: [host_string](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.8/usage/env.html#full-list-of-env-vars)

> Defines the current user/host/port which Fabric will connect to when
>   executing run, put and so forth. This is set by fab when iterating
>   over a previously set host list, and may also be manually set when
>   using Fabric as a library.

Hope this helps :)